# no termina el proceso de crear una app en react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

cuando uso el `npx create-react-app` en la consola dentro de la ruta de la carpeta donde voy a crear el proyecto jamas termina el proceso de crear la app
He reinstalado el node, he probado en linux y windows y jamas termina el proceso
tambien he intentado con

```
yarn create react-app nombre
npm init react-app nombre
npm i -g create-react-app nombre y luego create-react-app nombre
```

el caso es que empieza a instalar las dependencias necesarias, pero llega un momento que escribe en
la consola

> Done in 140.23s

y no avanza mas, la carpeta src jamas la crea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]